# Get number of printed copies

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I'm creating for myself, using VSTO, a word Add-in which helps me to do statistics about my printings (average number of letters, most used letter etc...) and I'm searching how to get the number of copies I selected just before printing.

When I use the Copies property of printerSettings :

```
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
ps.printerName=Document.ActivePrinter;
ps.copies;
```

It always return 1

And when I use the DEVMODE structure I just can't get a correct result.

I tried to get the PrintJob but my PrintJob collection was always empty.

So my question is :
Is there an easy way to get number of copies to print?
Every time I have looked for this question I have found how to set number of copies but never how to get it.

Comment: Which version of Word are we talking about?

Comment: I'm using Word 2013, but I'd like my add-in to work on any version if possible.